# Separation and analysis of an image

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, image-processing

Here's the scenario:
I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET framework 3.5. I am using `C#`. And for database I am using `MySQL`. I have a `picturebox` on a `form` and 10-12 `buttons` (each with some image manipulation function). On clicking one of the buttons `openfiledialog` box is shown up where the user can select the specific file to provide to the program. On clicking another button the program should perform the actions as explained below.
I have an image of a circuit. Suppose this is the image which is provided to the program. e.g.
[image: Circuit image]
What I intend to do is that - the program should hypothetically label the circuit as follows:
[image: Labeling of the circuit]
and then it should separate the image and store the information in a database.

Is there any way to do that. Can anyway tell me the approach to do that? Any help or suggestions please.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the images always clean and crisp 1-bit black/white images and do all terminals have holes like in your example? (If we're talking real circuit boards, you might also have SMD components which do not need holes in the copper)

Comment: In the beginning I am considering simple circuits only. And I am also ensuring the clarity of the images. If it turns out to be good and working giving somewhat satisfactory results then I may go for complex circuit boards and other complexities related to images.

Comment: I took a shot at doing this for fun yesterday night: http://virkkunen.net/js/circuit-labeler.html It's pretty slow because it does multiple passes using a sub-optimal algorithm (stolen from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling), but it kind of works. It's definitely possible to extract the traces and terminals from a through-hole copper layer with decent accuracy!

Answer (score 3):

In image processing, the problem of finding the 'parts' of the circuit is known as [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). If you are using C#, I believe that you can use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (a wrapper to the OpenCV library) to solve the first part of the problem. To do that, you have to consider that the white pixels are the background and that the black pixels are objects.

Now that you have the separated traces, the problem is reduced to finding and labeling the white dots. Again, you can solve it by connected component labeling, but now the objects are represented by white pixels and the background are the black pixels.

Comment: A "connected component labeling" algorithm would certainly be much less naive than what I suggested.

Comment: Probably, the algorithm would be very similar to the one that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

At least for your example case, a very simple algorithm would work.

1. Find a black pixel from the image
2. Using a flood-fill algorithm, find all the pixels connected to it, and separate it. That's one of your traces.
3. Working with the separated trace, find a white pixel and use a flood-fill algorithm to find all the pixels connected to it. If you run to the edge of the image, it's not a hole. If you don't, it might be a hole, or a loop in the trace. Use a threshold for the hole size to determine if it's a terminal hole or a loop.
4. Label the hole and remove it from consideration. Repeat until there are no more  unprocessed white pixels.
5. Remove the whole trace from consideration, and jump to 1.
6. When there are no more black pixels in consideration in step 1, you're done.

You should probably get pretty far with a basic image editing library that has a flood-fill function, a function to separate a certain color into a new image, and a function to replace colors (the last two are trivial to implement, and there are plenty of flood-fill algorithms available online). You can use different colors to mark different things, for instance, color everything "no in consideration" red. It also makes for an interesting visualization if you look at it in real time!

Comment: Thanks for the help. :) Let's see if I am able to put this into code form.

Comment: @OutOfBoundsException: I'm kind of tempted to try myself just to see if it works.